# ImageView fits height keeping aspect ratio

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have an that I want to fit the height, keeping the aspect ratio. Here is the image:

[image]

I want the red band fits the height of the grey row keeping its aspect ratio (the width of the ImageView should increase).
I have tried with the scaleType attribute in the xml but none works as I want.

Any suggestion please?

Comment: have you ever search ?

Comment: I think it's useless to answer your question. If you know how to solve it, enlighten me please.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to change this code of custom ImageView:

- keeps aspect ratio
- stretches image to width of imageview
- crops height overflow when necessary

**Code:**

```
public class ImageViewScaleTypeTopCrop extends ImageView {
    public ImageViewScaleTypeTopCrop(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setup();
    }

    public ImageViewScaleTypeTopCrop(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setup();
    }

    public ImageViewScaleTypeTopCrop(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setup();
    }

    private void setup() {
        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean setFrame(int frameLeft, int frameTop, int frameRight, int frameBottom) {

        float frameWidth = frameRight - frameLeft;
        float frameHeight = frameBottom - frameTop;

        if (getDrawable() != null) {

            Matrix matrix = getImageMatrix();
            float scaleFactor, scaleFactorWidth, scaleFactorHeight;

            scaleFactorWidth = (float) frameWidth / (float) getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
            scaleFactorHeight = (float) frameHeight / (float) getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();

            if (scaleFactorHeight > scaleFactorWidth) {
                scaleFactor = scaleFactorHeight;
            } else {
                scaleFactor = scaleFactorWidth;
            }

            matrix.setScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, 0, 0);
            setImageMatrix(matrix);
        }

        return super.setFrame(frameLeft, frameTop, frameRight, frameBottom);
    }

}
```